# blender 2.82 blurred image

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm a newbie I'm a trying to generate a decent texture using shaders, but I can't make it work.
The rendered image is blurred, as it was in motion, but it obviously is not, it's a simple plane with an applied shaders and the camera if fixed over it.

I tried evee as well cycles, I used f 8.0 and the plane as focus object, but nothing.

[image: configuration]
[image: rendered image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please add some images of the issue, your scene and your material setup. Without that it's just guessing.

Comment: sorry, I-m not very used to post on forums

Comment: Please use the tools of this site to add images to your post,  so that they are displayed and users don't have to go to links to understand your question. 
[How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498)

Comment: @user Good that you mention the f8. Could you try rendering again **without any** depth of field?

Comment: Tried, nothing changes.

Comment: I forgot, lens is configured as 50mm clip start 0.000001 and clip end 100 m